# Value from one html file to another html file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some (xyz)html files in my local system which is having some integer value in it.
I have created one(abc) html file having main summary of those files.
I want to show that integer value in my html file. How can i parse through xyz html files and store into my abc html file?

```
<table class="log" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Files</th><th>Errors</th>
</tr>
<tr class="a">
<td>225</td><td>2294</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is a content i have in my xyz html files.. and i need values 225  and 2294 to be extracted from here.

Comment: I didnot understand anything of your problem

Comment: You have to do a ajax request, but i think it's better to use a JSON file or something instead of html if it only contains a integer

Comment: bind the data ... and then you can set/get/reuse the data again everywhere without parsing it

Comment: @nirajkumar OP needs more accurate help than "binding data"..

Answer (score 2):

You can make ajax request from where you want to show value. by parsing html you can get value of specific field

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://test.com/page1.html",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        var html = $.parseHTML(data);
        var first = $(html).closest('.log').find('.a').find('td:eq(0)').html();
        var second = $(html).closest('.log').find('.a').find('td:eq(1)').html();

        alert(first+" "+ second);
    }
});
```

See [**Sample DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4gjmgqvd/) of parsing html as you want

Comment: Hi Manwal, thnx but the problem is i cannot edit those files as they are being generated by server after some execution at back end. I have only access to parse those files. I just want to read the value from there

Comment: No problem @jasmeet you don't have to edit them you can parse it. You can check where that value exists. Could you provide me some example where that value in html? like `<span>your_value</span>`.

Comment: I have added the html code above in my questions. 
Please refer it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to parse the HTML code you have, you can do that with several server-side scripting languages and also with JavaScript.

Here's a solution with JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadPage(href){
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", href, false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                return xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            function parseHTML(url){
                var my_arr = [];
                var el = document.createElement( 'div' );
                el.innerHTML = loadPage(url);
                var table_row = el.document.getElementsByClassName("a");
                for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
                    var new_arr = new Array();
                    my_arr.push(new_arr);
                    var r = x[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                    for(var j=0; j<r.length; j++){
                        var new_val = r[j].innerHTML;
                        my_arr[i].push(new_val);
                    }
                }
                return my_arr;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="parseHTML('my_url_path');">

    </body>

</html>
```

Here's a solution with PHP and SimpleHTMLDOM:

```
<?php
   $str = '<table class="log" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="100%"><tr><th>Files</th><th>Errors</th></tr><tr class="a"><td>225</td><td>2294</td></tr></table>';
   $html = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load from a string
    $html->load($str);

    $arr = array();
    $iterator = 0;
    // Loop over all the <tr> with a class ".a"
    $table_rows = $html->find("tr.a");
    foreach($table_rows as $tr){
        $arr[$iterator] = array();
        // Loop over all the <td> inside a <tr> with a class ".a"
        $table_divisions = $tr->find("td");
        foreach($table_divisions as $td){
            $arr[$iterator][] = $td->innertext;
        }
        $iterator++;
    }
?>
```

You need to download the library:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

Keep in mind that you need PHP 5.0+